# UIAlertView with UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput warning in iOS9

Tags: uialertview, ios9

I'm using `UIAlertView` with style `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`, it works but on iOS9 but I get the following log after the alter is shown:

the behavior of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is not defined because 
    the item height must be less than the height of the `UICollectionView` minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

> The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is
>   <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x1262edd40>, and it is
>   attached to ;
>   layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize:
>   {0, 0}> collection view layout:
>   <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x1262edd40>.

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Same code works on iOS8 with no warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Have you tried to put a frame around your alertController like this?

```
alertController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 400.0); // Workaround iOS8.3 bug - set this to larger than you'll need
```

Comment: Does it solve the problem at your side or do you just want to tell that you'd also like to have a solution?

Comment: Found it on the net and played around ... but it did not solve the problem for me :-(